# 2g 3g and wifi at the same time, rmnet0 must stay active

Tags: wifi, 3g, gprs

phone: Sony Ericsson x8 - rooted

I see with ifconfig, that when I enable wifi in settings, rmnet0 (which represents 2g/3g) will disappear - only wlan0 will show up on ifconfig then. As soon as I disable wlan0, I can see rmnet0 again...

There is one process which I like to run on 2g/3g at all times, never on wifi. In my process I I can configure on which IP it will bind.

Therefore I need to find a way, to let rmnet0 always stay alive, even when wifi is also enabled. How can I do that?

(I am not developing an app. I am looking for something like a linux command. If needed I would also exchange/flash system files, got a custom rom anyway. The process is a linux app, which runs inside Debian Linux on top of Android using chroot. Therefore I guess the java/sdk restrictions do not matter here, as I have full system access.)